# Flat file NoSQL solution

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, nosql

Is there a built-in way in SQLite (or similar) to keep the best of both worlds SQL / NoSQL, for small projects, i.e.:

- stored **in a (flat) file** like SQLite (no client/server scheme, no server to install; more precisely : nothing else to install except `pip install <package>`)
- possibility to store rows as `dict`, *without* having a common structure for each row, like NoSQL databases
- support of simple queries

Example:

```
db = NoSQLite('test.db')
db.addrow({'name': 'john doe', 'balance': 1000, 'data': [1, 73.23, 18]})
db.addrow({'name': 'alice', 'balance': 2000, 'email': 'a@b.com'})
for row in db.find('balance > 1500'):
    print(row)

# {'id': 'f565a9fd3a', 'name': 'alice', 'balance': 2000, 'email': 'a@b.com'}   # id was auto-generated
```

Note: I have constantly been amazed along the years by how many interesting features are in fact possible with SQLite in a few lines of code, that's why I'm asking if what I describe here could maybe be available simply with SQLite by using only a few SQLite core features.

PS: [`shelve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html) *could* look like a solution but in fact it's just a persistent key/value store, and it doesn't have query/`find` functions; also [`bsddb`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bsddb.html) (BerkeleyDB for Python) looks deprecated and has no query feature with a similar API.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible via using the [JSON1](https://sqlite.org/json1.html) extension to query JSON data stored in a column, yes:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE test(data TEXT);
sqlite> INSERT INTO test VALUES ('{"name":"john doe","balance":1000,"data":[1,73.23,18]}');
sqlite> INSERT INTO test VALUES ('{"name":"alice","balance":2000,"email":"a@b.com"}');
sqlite> SELECT * FROM test WHERE json_extract(data, '$.balance') > 1500;
data
--------------------------------------------------
{"name":"alice","balance":2000,"email":"a@b.com"}
```

---

If you're going to be querying the same field a lot, you can make it more efficient by adding an index on the expression:

```
CREATE INDEX test_idx_balance ON test(json_extract(data, '$.balance'));
```

will use that index on the above query instead of scanning every single row.

Comment: Wow, nice solution! Then I guess, it would loop over *the whole* DB to do `find('name="john doe"')`? I imagine it's like this because SQLite has to `json_extract` all rows to test if the name matches, is it right?

Comment: @Basj You *might* be able to do something with an [index on an expression](https://www.sqlite.org/expridx.html), but I haven't tried it. Otherwise, yes, it'd have to look at every row - note I didn't say doing this was a *good* idea, just that it can be done. :)

Comment: Okay, an index on an expression will work with `json_extract`().

Comment: Thanks! Could you include an example of how the query should be done, after having created an index with `CREATE INDEX test_idx_balance ON test(json_extract(data, '$.balance'));`?

Answer (score 9):

### SQLite

- `JSON1` extension and `json_extract` (see accepted answer). Example:

  ```
  import sqlite3, json  # tested with precompiled Windows binaries from https://www.sqlite.org/download.html (sqlite3.dll copied in C:\Python37\DLLs)

  class sqlitenosql:
      def __init__(self, f):
          self.db = sqlite3.connect(f)
          self.db.execute('CREATE TABLE test(data TEXT);')

      def close(self):
          self.db.commit()
          self.db.close()

      def addrow(self, d):
          self.db.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES (?);", (json.dumps(d),))

      def find(self, query):
          for k, v in query.items():
              if isinstance(v, str):
                  query[k] = f"'{v}'"
          q = ' AND '.join(f" json_extract(data, '$.{k}') = {v}" for k, v in query.items())
          for r in self.db.execute(f"SELECT * FROM test WHERE {q}"):
              yield r[0]

  db = sqlitenosql(':memory:')
  db.addrow({'name': 'john', 'balance': 1000, 'data': [1, 73.23, 18], 'abc': 'hello'})
  db.addrow({'name': 'alice', 'balance': 2000, 'email': 'a@b.com'})
  db.addrow({'name': 'bob', 'balance': 1000})
  db.addrow({'name': 'richard', 'balance': 1000, 'abc': 'hello'})
  for r in db.find({'balance': 1000, 'abc': 'hello'}):
      print(r)
  # {"name": "john", "balance": 1000, "data": [1, 73.23, 18], "abc": "hello"}
  # {"name": "richard", "balance": 1000, "abc": "hello"}    
  db.close()
  ```
- [sqlitedict](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/sqlitedict) as mentioned in [Key: value store in Python for possibly 100 GB of data, without client/server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47233562/key-value-store-in-python-for-possibly-100-gb-of-data-without-client-server/48305350#48305350) and [Use SQLite as a key:value store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47237807/use-sqlite-as-a-keyvalue-store/47238001#47238001) 
  with:

  key = an ID

  value = the dict we want to store, e.g. `{'name': 'alice', 'balance': 2000, 'email': 'a@b.com'}`
- Further reading about use of SQLite with JSON: https://community.esri.com/groups/appstudio/blog/2018/08/21/working-with-json-in-sqlite-databases

### TinyDB

[TinyDB](https://tinydb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) looks like a good solution:

```
>>> from tinydb import TinyDB, Query
>>> db = TinyDB('path/to/db.json')
>>> User = Query()
>>> db.insert({'name': 'John', 'age': 22})
>>> db.search(User.name == 'John')
[{'name': 'John', 'age': 22}]
```

However, the documentation mentions that it's *not* the right tool if we need:

> - access from multiple processes or threads,
> - creating indexes for tables,
> - an HTTP server,
> - managing relationships between tables or similar,
> - ACID guarantees

So it's a half solution :)

### Oher solutions

Seems interesting too : [WhiteDB](http://whitedb.org/index.html)

Comment: Your answer helped me no end with the quick solution i needed. adapted your code and used jsonpickle to handle encoding which returns the class type on querying. As the question is closed i will post my solution as a gist here to help future devs out.
https://gist.github.com/ahancock1/72e459e294875988f4e6138d348122de